# how to join a string and variable to th:src

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I want spring to search an image under path: /upload-dir/ID.jpg

ID is a variable that depends on the object's id.

Ive made something like this:

```
th:src="|@{/upload-dir/}  ${dog.id} .jpg|"
```

but this is not working at all. I beg for any advice how to make it work :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following structure to do so.

```
th:src="@{'/upload-dir/' + ${dog.id} + '.jpg'}"
```